# My controller for register and login is not working (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, backend

please help me... My controller for registration and login is not working. Whenever I input the data in either login or register it will back to register and login view and not the index/home nor the data that I input enter mysql.

I create it like when I success in inputting the data on register it will direct to login then when you login it will direct to home. Other is login, when I login it will direct to home if it can login.

**Controller: Member.php**

```
   class Member extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
    $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
    $this->load->model("Member_model");
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('front/login');
}

public function Login() {
    $this->load->view('front/login');
}

public function Register() {
    $this->load->view('front/register');
}

public function profile() {

    if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE) {

        $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Please login first to view");
        redirect('Member/Login');
    }
    $this->load->view('front/home');
}
```

}

**Controller: Register.php**

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
        $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
        $this->load->model("Member_model");
    }

    public function registerMember() {
        //validate  the data taken through the register form
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|is_unique[member.username]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[password]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            //load the model to connect to the db
            $this->load->model('Member_model');
            $this->Member_model->insertMember();

            //set message to be shown when registration is completed
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','You are registered!');
            redirect('Member/Login');

        } else {
            $this->load->view('front/register');
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller: Login.php**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
        $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
        $this->load->model("Member_model");
    }

    public function loginMember() {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('front/login');

        } else {

            $this->load->model('Member_model');
            $reslt = $this->Member_model->checkLogin();

            if ($reslt != false) {

                //set session
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = sha1($_POST['password']);

                //fetch from databse
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('member');
                $this->db->where(array('username' => $username , 'password' => $password));
                $query = $this->db->get();

                $member = $query->row();

                //if use exists
                if ($member->username) {

                    //login message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("success","You are logged in");

                    //set session variables
                    $_SESSION['user_logged'] = TRUE;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $member->username;

                    //redirect
                   redirect('Member/profile','refresh');
                }
            } else {

                //wrong credentials
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Username or Password invalid!');
                redirect('Member/Login');

            }
        }

    }

    //logging out of a user
    public function logoutMember() {
        unset($_SESSION);
        redirect('Member/Login');
    }
}
```

**Model: Member_model.php**

```
class Member_model extends CI_Model {

public function insertMember () {

    //insert data
    $data = array(
        //assign data into array elements
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password'))
    );
    //insert data to the database
    $this->db->insert('member',$data);
}

public function checkLogin() {

    //enter username and password
    $username = $this->input->post('username',TRUE);
    $password = sha1($this->input->post('password',TRUE));

    //fetch data from database
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $res = $this->db->get('member');

    //check if there's a user with the above inputs
    if ($res->num_rows() == 1) {

        //retrieve the details of the user
        return $res->result();

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}}
```

**View:
Register.php**

```
<body class="background-login">
    <div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">
        <h1> SignUp </h1>
        <div class="main-agileinfo">
            <div class="agileits-top">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('register/registerMember'); ?>" >                    

                    <input class="text" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter a username">

                    <input class="text email" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">

                    <input class="text" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter a password">

                    <input class="text w3lpass" type="password" id="conf_password" name="conf_password" placeholder="Confirm your password">

                    <div class="wthree-text">
                        <label class="anim">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required="">
                            <span>I Agree To The Terms & Conditions</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="clear"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="SignUp">
                </form>
                <p>Already have an Account? <a href="<?php echo site_url('Member/Login'); ?>"> Login Now!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Login.php**

```
 <body class="background-login">
    <div class="main-w3layouts wrapper">
        <h1> SignIn </h1>
        <div class="main-agileinfo">
            <div class="agileits-top">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('Login/loginMember'); ?>" >                        
                    <input class="text" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your username"><br>
                    <input class="text" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
                </form>
                <p>Don't have an Account? <a href="<?php echo site_url('Member/Register'); ?>"> SignUp NOW!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I even chop my code into part like this, but the problem still the same... Is just like the if form_validation->run is not running and just got cut to else...

So the problem is: 
When I input data it will not enter the data or redirect to another page.
*register -> it will direct to register after i submit the data
What I want is when I submit the data it will direct to login.
*login -> it will direct to login after i submit the data
What I want is when I submit the data it will direct to home.
[image: register] -> result -> [image: regis_result]

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: I cannot input and everytime I input data it will back to form login and register without inputting the data

Comment: <form action="#" method="post">

you need to set the controller path in action attribute, to which controller the form data has to be posted.

Comment: You mean I need to add function login or register from controller in form action like this:                                                                                                         
<form action="login" method="post">
<form action="register" method="post">

Comment: But, it still not function...

Comment: you need to give the full path like

action="<?php echo base_url("Member/login") ?>"

Comment: Sorry, it still not function after I click button register or login it will back to register and login

Comment: and no data being inputted

Comment: I also already tried to erase the <form action="#" method="post"> but it still worked the same

Comment: you have to pass the form data to login controller right? that was the issue you are facing or else any other issue?

Comment: yes, but it still not working the data that I input somehow not enter the database

Comment: Oh also teh page keep on appearing on same page even after i input the data.. is like is not being read at all

Comment: I missed to notice two form in your view page. as Mr.Dolor mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52849095/9988189... remove one form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this case . I solved it by passing `$this` in to `run()`

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == TRUE)
```

You can pass array in `where` condition in checkLogin function

```
$where_array = array('username' => $username,'password' => $password);
$this->db->where($where_array);
$res = $this->db->get('member');
```

Hope it help you too!

Comment: Thank you, but now my login cannot enter another page when i input the data.. it seems that this if code is wrong and always change to else:  if ($reslt != false)

Comment: There also you added `$this` inside `run()` ? `if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE)` @KurodaAyumu

Comment: Check the records returned by `dd($res)` in `checkLogin` in `Member_model`

Comment: if there are more than one records for same user than also it can return to false

Comment: I already added $this in the code if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE)... but somehow the if($reslt != false) is not working

Comment: what does `dd($res)` return in Member model checkLogin function? and check my edited answer @KurodaAyumu

Comment: to check the user that login if it true then it will return the result, but if it false then it will return false

Comment: @KurodaAyumu what i am trying to say is that you are checking `$res->num_rows() == 1` in checkLogin function what does `$res->num_rows()` return while login??

Comment: it supposed to return the username

Comment: @KurodaAyumu  i dont think so because `num_rows()` function returns the number of rows from database that are matched with your username and password

Comment: oh.. right, I already change the code to $where_array = array('username' => $username,'password' => $password);
$this->db->where($where_array);
$res = $this->db->get('member'); but it still not function... do you think that there is something wrong with my if ($reslt != false)  in function loginMember in Controller Login?

Comment: Can you check if there is record in your database of the username and password you are trying? and change `if($reslt != false)` with `if($reslt)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182394/discussion-between-leena-patel-and-kuroda-ayumu).

Comment: yet it still change to else eror

Comment: Change `if ($res->num_rows() == 1) {` with `if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {` in your `checkLogin` function in `Member_model.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the form_open function and html form tag at the same time, so remove anyone from it and pass the whole path in the action.

If you use form_open function then please add the form_close function.

Answer (score 0):

in your register and login view

```
                <?= form_open() ?>
                <form action="#" method="post">
```

you added this. this is wrong.at a same time you open two form you need to remove a  line.and add some action to form for example

```
<form action="<?= base_url('yourControllerName/YourMethodname')?>" method='post'></form>
```

and second thing in Member.php Controller you added this line

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
        Some code
    }
```

this is wrong you need this

```
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
```

please check and ping me......

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your base_url in config.php is not null.

In register.php remove `<?=form_open('member/login')?>` and `<?= form_close() ?>`

Instead add, `<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('Member/register'); ?>" >`
 and
 `</form>`

Comment: I still cannot input the data and after i input the data it will redirect to first page

Comment: nope, it just back to the login or register view page without entering the data or direct to another page

Comment: Have you set the base_url in config.php ?

Comment: I have edited my above code. let me know what error it gives then.

Comment: Nope, it still the same after i submit the data it still go to the same page without inputting the data to database

Comment: In the register function change $this->load->view('front/login'); into print_r("created"); and $this->load->view('front/register'); into print_r("error");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182327/discussion-between-shavindi-pathirana-and-kuroda-ayumu).

Comment: I already, change the code and differ it to part but it still not function right

Answer (score 0):

redirect your page:

//login

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
        { 
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $email    = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

           $user= $this->member_model->create_user();
if($user >0){
redirect('front/home'); 
        } else { 
           redirect('front/login'); 
        }
}
```

you can same as in singup

Comment: the output is blank

Comment: in register.php controller put in else part 

  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>